# I am not able to connect to my xampp

Tags: apache-http-server, xampp

I have xampp running on my dell. This is on a network. It was running fine until I had to shut down the computer to move to another location in the building. Now after restarting the xampp I am unable to connect to it from another computer. I  have tried localhost directly from the dell system and it is still not working.

I check the status of Xampp and all is working and displaying running, no errors on start up or anything like that. I check my IP Address to make sure that it did not change during the process of the move. I really need some help in getting this resolved.

(I am running XAMPP V3.2.1)

Below you will find what my control panel is displaying and I am not able to access localhost.

[image: cpanel]

Answer (score -1):

Check if you have Skype running on that machine.

Skype uses TCP port 80 as part of its protocol, which is also the default port for HTTP webservers. It is possible Skype is preventing the access to the Apache server.

Comment: Yes but I know of that issue and already uninstalled skype. Problem still exist. The control panel is showing that apache is running and what ports it's using and PID's being used. I am just not able to access localhost

Comment: I updated the questions to show what my control panel is displaying and I am still not able to access the localhost.